# Using jQAssistant with Git Plugin to determine changed files by author

Tags: git, neo4j, cypher, jqassistant

I'm trying to build a query to list all files changed by an author (to later filter them by other information based on stereotypes).

Currently the query returns way to many files - probably due to merges (?)

My understanding of the Git / Graph Model is this:

[image]

The current query I use:

```
MATCH (author:Git:Author)-[:COMMITTED]->(commit:Git:Commit)-[cc:CONTAINS_CHANGE]->(change:Git:Change)-[]->(file:Git:File)
WHERE author.email="developer-of-interest@email-address.com"
RETURN file.relativePath
ORDER BY file.relativePath ASC
```

This returns way too many files. Some random samples I took a look at does not show that developer in the git history of that file. I assume this happens due to some merges?

The random sample shows that author of interest and some path to the file:
[image]

But using the IDE to look into the git history of that file does not show the author in there.

Something that returns a list much closer to my expected result with git commands:

```
git log --no-merges --author="developer-of-interest" --name-only --pretty=format:"" | sort -u
```

Looking at the nodes and relations (yellow one points to the file I never touched) nothing looks like a hint to exclude that specific commit:
[image]

I'm pretty sure the Neo4j query is somehow wrong?

How can I ignore those commits caused by merges? (if that is the issue)

I don't know how git log is able to filter out those commits but with jqassert and the git plugin that information seems to be lost?

Comment: If the model is accurate, the query looks correct. Double check your data?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to return distinct files:

```
MATCH (author:Git:Author)-[:COMMITTED]->(:Git:Commit)-[:CONTAINS_CHANGE]->(:Git:Change)-->(file:Git:File)
WHERE author.email="developer-of-interest@email-address.com"
WITH DISTINCT file
RETURN file.relativePath
ORDER BY file.relativePath ASC
```

Also, omit the `:Git` label from your query if that would return the same results. The query would run faster with less filtering.

In addition, if there are many types of relationships between `Change` and `File` nodes, perhaps some are not appropriate for you use case. If so, you should be specific about the desired relationship types.

Finally, there may be properties somewhere on matched paths that you need to use to filter out unwanted files.

Comment: This is correct if it's just duplicates @wemu is seeing. But it seems there are files not touched by the author.

Comment: The original query did not specify any types for the relationship between `Change` and `File`, so I followed suit. But if there are relationship types that are inappropriate for the use case, the query should be more specific about the types. As in `-[:TYPE1|TYPE2|TYPE3]->`.

Comment: thanks for the inputs! It is of course true that the DISTINCT reduces the number of files - that was missing. But there are still way too many files I never touched (other than through merges/rebasing). The queries run very fast anyway so I currently don't bother with the types too much. Only a few ms difference.
The relationships between Change and File seem ok (example above has UPDATES and MODIFIES which is ok). Only the Commit type has a property message="Merge remote-tracking branch..." - otherwise I don't see how to exclude that commit. I'm confused...

Comment: Yes, make use of properties to filter out (in the `WHERE` clause) unwanted files.

Comment: I've added another image of the commits of one user and marked the one that points to the file that was not touched (according to the git log). Nothing seems to be wrong there, the first commit down the "has_parent" path was a merge conflict. But there is no obvious property to exclude that path.